# PIA Client installation on Ubuntu system with encrypted home folder (ecryptfs)

Tags: networking, bash, vpn, openvpn

How can I get the PIA client for Ubuntu working on a system using ecryptfs?

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 3):

OP's answer (taken from the question)

> Thanks to Chris W. and Mason D. at PIA Support for the help getting
>   the PIA client for Ubuntu working on a system using ecryptfs! I
>   thought I should share this guide I compiled from information I was
>   given as well as things I discovered with anyone else experiencing
>   issues with the PIA client on Ubuntu using an encrypted home
>   partition.    First of all, untar the installer file using tar xzvf and
>   run ./pia-v62-installer.sh and follow the normal installation prompt.
>   The applet will open and here you should enter your username and
>   password and change desired port settings and security, all of which
>   will remain after you move the directory later.   Note that the PIA
>   client will NOT connect because, according to Mason D., "This error
>   message normally appears when you have an encrypted home directory
>   using eCryptfs. Our application makes use of suid; SUID stands for Set
>   User ID. Essentially, this lets our application run as root without
>   requiring the user to enter a password. However, eCryptfs, does not
>   allow suid binaries in users home directories to be executed. It is
>   set this way by default to prevent privilege escalation attacks."
>   Then, you must type the following in your terminal:
>
> ```
> cd /
> mkdir pia
> sudo chown root:root pia
> sudo mv /home/your_username/.pia_manager /pia/.pia_manager
> ln -s /pia/.pia_manager /home/your_username/.pia_manager
> ```
>
> In summary, you are creating a new directory for pia to occupy in the
>   root filesystem, changing the access permissions to the root default,
>   moving the application files there, and creating a symbolic link with
>   the same name in your home directory so that dependencies are not
>   broken (it will not work if you fail to create the symbolic link).
>
> In Ubuntu, the process of connecting with ipv6 leak protection enabled
>   in the PIA client also appears to be faster when ipv6 is disabled for
>   the regular internet connection in the system network manager. Click
>   the network-manager applet, then go to 'Edit Connections' =>
>   'Your_Network' => 'Edit'. In the 'IPv4 Settings' tab, check 'Require
>   IPv4 addressing for this connection to complete', under 'Method'
>   choose 'Automatic DHCP addresses only', then click the 'IPv6 Settings'
>   tab and under 'Method' and select 'Ignore' to disable ipv6. The reason
>   why disabling ipv6 is important is because your device's physical MAC
>   address is included in an ipv6 address (very, very bad for privacy).
>
> Now, take notice of the pia.sh file placed in your home ~/ directory
>   from the installer. Modify the permissions to that of a default script
>   using the command 'chmod 755 ~/pia.sh', and change the name to
>   pia-manager using the command 'mv ~/pia.sh ~/pia-manager'. Create a
>   directory for user-defined scripts, using 'mkdir ~/Documents/scripts',
>   then move the script file there using 'mv ~/pia-manager
>   ~/Documents/scripts'. Now open the pia-manager file with your favorite
>   text editor (I like emacs, type 'emacs -nw
>   ~/Documents/scripts/pia-manager') and change the content to the
>   following:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> /pia/.pia_manager/pia_manager/run.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &
> ```
>
> Save the file (in emacs it's ctrl-x, ctrl-s) and then edit your path
>   using 'sudo emacs -nw /etc/environment' to include the directory
>   /home/your_username/Documents/scripts. Make sure to add a colon :
>   after the last path in the file, then append the path to your scripts
>   directory. Your file should look something like this:
>
> ```
> PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/Qt/5.7/gcc_64/bin:/home/your_username/Documents/scripts"
> ```
>
> Now for the icing on the cake (and correct startup for that matter),
>   open Startup Applications from the Unity dash, select 'Private
>   Internet Access'=>'Edit' and delete the whole line in the 'Command'
>   box and replace it with the name of your script, 'pia-manager'. Reboot
>   your computer, and the PIA client should automatically connect.   Note
>   that you can now exit the application and at any time relaunch the PIA
>   client using your script by simply typing 'pia-manager' anywhere in
>   your filesystem in a terminal! Because this script is in your path,
>   tab completion also applies, making it very convenient to launch the
>   PIA client. I hope you found this guide useful and informative!